# How to prevent Entity Framework from converting empty strings to null in database-first approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have to insert empty strings in a non-nullable varchar field in an oracle db.
The property of the object I'm trying to save is set to **empty string**, but when I call *SaveChanges* I get an error because EF converts my empty string to null.
I know that, in code-first approach, there you can use **ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false**: is there a way to achieve the same behavior with **database-first** approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in Oracle (at least for now) the empty string is treated as null.
Therefore there is no way to save an empty string in a varchar field.

> Note:Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings the same as nulls.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071)

Comment: Has anyone looked into a workaround for this ? Ideally one which doesn't involve modifying the model or the context to become Oracle specific... I looked into `SaveChangesInterceptor` and `IMaterializingInterceptor` but it seems that solutions like this would come with a significant performance cost.